# How to force method termination to affect the one it is called in

Tags: ruby

Let say there are three methods:

```
def foo
  puts :start
  x = 1
  bar(x) # I want the method to terminate here
  baz
end

def bar(x)
  if x < 2
    puts :finish_here
    return
  else
    puts :continue
  end
end

def baz
  puts :finish
end

foo
#=> start
#=> finish_here
#=> finish
#=> nil
```

Is there any (sane) way I could make the call to `bar(x)` to be treated as if its code was executed in the scope of `foo`, so that the `return` terminates the `foo`?

So the expected output of foo would be:

```
foo
#=> start
#=> finish_here
#=> nil
```

## EDIT

**Using a Proc object instead of method or raising an exception or `exit`ing the whole program are not the options.**

Comment: Is raising an exception an option?

Comment: @spickermann unfortunately no, I just need to return the string and terminate. Of course, it is simplified example

Comment: Technically, you could pass the current binding from `foo` to `bar` and call `binding.eval('return')` from within `bar`. But of course, you would never do this ;-)

Comment: That would only work if `bar` would be a `Proc`. Procs return from the enclosing scope.

Comment: @eugen know about procs, but would like to know, if similar behavior possible with method :)

Comment: What use case mandates this convoluted processing?

Answer (score 6):

You can simulate that using `throw`/`catch` (which is **not** `rescue`/`raise`):

```
def foo
  puts :start
  x = 1
  catch(:return) do
    bar(x) # I want the method to terminate here
    baz
  end
end

def bar(x)
  if x < 2
    puts :finish_here
    throw :return
  else
    puts :continue
  end
end

def baz
  puts :finish
end

foo
```

This is **not** using `raise`/`rescue`.

The `catch` block is like an exception handler... But `throw`/`catch` in Ruby is usually used to handle non-exceptional situations, e.g., break out of inner loops, etc.

The `throw` will traverse its callstack to try and find an associated `catch` block with the **same label** (if you `catch(:foo)` but `throw :bar`, that's not going to work).

This is easier than returning a value to indicate termination, if you have a lot of nested calls, and any of them might want to return.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80052f1665824756).

Answer (score 1):

Following [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan)'s "proposal" in the comments, this seems to work:

```
alias :original_foo :foo

def foo
  $last_binding = binding
  original_foo
end

def bar(x)
  if x < 2
    puts :finish_here
    eval("return", $last_binding)
  else
    puts :continue
  end
end
```

If you can modify `foo` (and `bar`), I'd rather signal termination request from `bar` to `foo` through the return value. Like so:

```
def foo
  puts :start
  x = 1
  return if bar(x) == :out # I want the method to terminate here
  baz
end

def bar(x)
  if x < 2
    puts :finish_here
    return :out
  else
    puts :continue
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually currently have it done similar to your latter example, but I call `bar` in 4 other methods, thus wanted something nice an short..

Comment: `return if bar(x) == :out` is the shortest solution that there is really

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this in pure ruby without some cooperation of the calling method, as outlined in the other answers.

If you are willing to restrict yourself to MRI and to use additional libraries, you could use the [binding_of_caller](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) gem (extracted from pry): this uses a C extension to allows you to get the binding object for the calling method (you can go as far up the call tree as you want).

```
require 'binding_of_caller'
def foo
  puts :start
  x = 1
  bar(x) # I want the method to terminate here
  baz
end

def bar(x)
  if x < 2
    puts :finish_here
    binding.of_caller(1).eval("return")
  else
    puts :continue
  end
end

def baz
  puts :finish
end

foo
```

This does produce the output you want, but as has been commented this is rather unusual and likely to cause surprises. The author of the gem also warns against using in production

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning from `bar` you could call `exit`

```
def bar(x)
  puts :finish_here
  exit if x > 2
end
```

**Update:**

If you need to continue execution in your original method, you could use exceptions to do this:

I would define your own exception class for this purpose

```
class MyCustomError < StandardError; end

def bar(x)
  puts :finish_here
  raise MyCustomError if x > 2
end
```

Then you can rescue from this error to finish whatever processing you need to:

```
def foo
  puts :start
  x = 1
  bar(x) # I want the method to terminate here
  baz
rescue MyCustomError
  # do your remaining things here
end
```

Comment: This will exit the whole program not just the caller.

Comment: That was my understanding of what he wanted

Comment: I need to finish the method on the return, not the program

Comment: Ah ok. Well, using exceptions could be a solution. I'll update my answer

Comment: Why? What sensible reason do you have for not using exceptions?

Comment: exceptions do not look clean/elegant enough for me in this case. I need something nicer (if it exists, otherwise I'll just leave the code from `bar` inside the `foo` and that's it)

Comment: Changing the control flow of one method from another method is never clean nor elegant. A method should be encapsulated and not mess around with it's caller.